# Change text color in table, preserve ability

Tags: tables, spacing, color

I'm having difficulty creating a new command for `\rowstyle` that allows me to color the text of different rows in a table and preserve my ability to space out the columns and not induce space between the lines. I'm trying to stay away from Tabu. Here is what I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{threeparttable}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
 \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
 \@rowstyle\ignorespaces%
}
\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
>{\gdef\@rowstyle{}}%
}
\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
>{\@rowstyle}%
}

 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!] \small
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{ =p{2.0cm}  +C{1.0cm} +C{1.0cm}  +C{1.0cm}   +C{1.0cm} +C{1.0cm}   +C{1.0cm}  }
 \hline
1 & -0.043 & -0.206 & -0.01 & -0.46 & 0.336 & 0.191 \\ 
\rowstyle{\color{red}}
2 & (0.902) & (0.63) & (1) & (0.286) & (0.259) & (0.502) \\ 
\rowstyle{\color{blue}}
3 & 119 & 111 & 120 & 106 & 119 & 141 \\
\rowstyle{\color{black}}
 4 & -0.04 & -0.182 & 0.074 & -0.227 & -0.189 & 0.127 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
  \footnotesize
  \item \textbf{Note:} This table XYZ. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Thanks for any and all thoughts.

Comment: Do remember math mode in the table as well, there is no meaning to hyphen 0.04 ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\color` introduces a whatsit (`\special`). At the start of a `p` column vertical mode is in force, that means the whatsit becomes the top of the cell. As `p` columns are aligned at the base line, the following text line is put below the current row base line. Adding `\leavevmode` helps, then the whatsit is put at the begin of the first text line in horizontal mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{threeparttable}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \makeatletter
 \newcommand*{\@rowstyle}{}
\newcommand*{\rowstyle}[1]{% sets the style of the next row
  \gdef\@rowstyle{#1}%
  \leavevmode\@rowstyle
  \ignorespaces
}
\newcolumntype{=}{% resets the row style
  >{\gdef\@rowstyle{}\ignorespaces}%
}
\newcolumntype{+}{% adds the current row style to the next column
  >{\leavevmode\@rowstyle\ignorespaces}%
}

 \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \makeatother
 \begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!] \small
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{ =p{2.0cm}  +C{1.0cm} +C{1.0cm}  +C{1.0cm}   +C{1.0cm} +C{1.0cm}  +C{1.0cm}}
 \hline
1 & -0.043 & -0.206 & -0.01 & -0.46 & 0.336 & 0.191 \\
\rowstyle{\color{red}}
2 & (0.902) & (0.63) & (1) & (0.286) & (0.259) & (0.502) \\
\rowstyle{\color{blue}}
3 & 119 & 111 & 120 & 106 & 119 & 141 \\
\rowstyle{\color{black}}
 4 & -0.04 & -0.182 & 0.074 & -0.227 & -0.189 & 0.127 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
  \footnotesize
  \item \textbf{Note:} This table XYZ.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]