# Using \color in a paragraph column inside a tabular environment results in a line break

Tags: tables, macros, color, line-breaking

Some of my documents are compiled into multiple outputs. Some Versions contain certain parts, while other versions contain only a placeholder. For this purpose I have a macro `\markup` that colors its argument red in some versions and omits it in others. Obviously that macro should work just about anywhere, for example in normal text, inside tables, in captions or headlines, etc.

Now when I use `\markup` (or just `\color`) in a `p` column inside a `tabular` environment, it creates an odd line break that shouldn't really be there. When used in other column types such as `c`, there is no line break:

[image: Broken line breaks]

I know I could use `\textcolor` instead of `\color` (which fixes the issue) but then my macro wouldn't work when the argument contains paragraphs, since `\textcolor` is not `\long`. Are there other ways to fix that weird linebreak, accept lone arguments, and still have a macro that works in (nearly) all situations?

```
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% The actual \markup macro is a bit more complicated and contains an \if
\newcommand\markup[1]{{\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| p{2cm} | c |} 
        \hline
        p\{2cm\}   & c          \\ \hline
        \markup{1} & 2          \\ \hline
        3          & \markup{4} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Change text color in table, preserve ability](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119769/16967).

Comment: True, but there's a lot more clutter in that question (which is probably the reason I didn't find it). ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define `\markup` to start with `\leavevmode`. Sorry it's not my fault:-)

Comment: Why would it be your fault?

Comment: @Fritz I did the colour support in latex:-)

Answer (score 1):

If a manual correction is enough...

```
\documentclass[margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% The actual \markup macro is a bit more complicated and contains an \if
\newcommand\markup[1]{{\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| p{2cm} | c |} 
        \hline
        p\{2cm\}   & c          \\ \hline
      \noindent\markup{1} & {2}          \\ \hline
        3          & \markup{4} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]